# Optimizing fetching api data with custom React hooks on searching by keyword change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I am new to React Hooks. I write a small code that displays a list of courses to the user. It contains 2 main components `CourseList` and `Course` and a custom hook `useCourseList`. Here is the code of the custom hook:

```
function useCourseList(searchString) {
  const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleCourseListUpdating(nextCourses) {
      setCourses(nextCourses);
    }

    getCourses(searchString, handleCourseListUpdating)

    return () => {
      setCourses([]);
    }
  }, [searchString]);

  return courses;
}
```

The above code is fetching api data by a search string via `getCourses` function. Then it updates the retrieved data to `courses` state which is rendered by `CourseList` component. The `useEffect` function is triggered with `searchString` as its dependencies to keep updating courses' data once the search string changes.

The web browser refreshes many times corresponding with every single character change of the search string although the data results on those keyword changes are the same.
For example, we are looking for a game course with keyword "Game". Then it calls 4 times on useEffect one by one with "G", "Ga", "Gam", and "Game". Those keywords give the same results with my current api data but they are constantly updated React DOM via web interface. **That leads to browser twinkling 4 times** which is unnecessary. It also gives a bad user experience.

**Is there any solution to prevent updating UI as data are still consistent? Is there any problem with the data flow?**

For demonstration, you can see the full sample code here:
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/course-list-sample-lr119?file=/src/components/CourseList.jsx&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: An [useDebounce](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/) hook might be helpful.

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't put `() => { setCourses([]); }` as a cleanup for the `useEffect` hook. The reason you put it there maybe because you think it can give the user some instance feedback but IMO it is possible that it actually causes more flickering. So I agree with @Shubham Khatri's answer.

Comment: @Hangindev Cool! I didn't think debounce pattern is also applicable to a react hook. Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried to implement it to my demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/course-list-usedebounce-o24xb). It actually has better ui experience but the browser still gets twinkling. Do you have any idea to improve it smoother in term of pure react hooks?

Comment: @Hangindev Thanks. I agree with you two : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 changes you can make for a better ui experience

- Debounce the API call for search
- Do not set the state to empty in useEffect cleanup

You can choose to write your own custom debounce function or use it from a library such as lodash or underscore. Once you do that you can use `useMemo` to create a debounced instance of the getCourses function and call it inside useEffect

```
const debounce = (fn, delay) => {
  let timer = null;
  return function(...args) {
    if (timer){
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      fn.apply(this, args);
    }, delay)
  }
}
// A custom Hook
function useCourseList(searchString) {
  const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);
  const getDebouncedCourses = useMemo(() => debounce(getCourses, 300), []);
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleCourseListUpdating(courses) {
      setCourses(courses);
    }

    getDebouncedCourses(searchString, handleCourseListUpdating);
  }, [searchString, getDebouncedCourses]);

  return courses;
}

// CourseList component
function CourseList() {
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState('');
  const courses = useCourseList(searchString)

  return (
    <div>
      {courses ? (
        <div>
          <TextField style={{ padding: 24 }}
            id="searchInput"
            placeholder="Search for Courses"
            margin="normal"
            onChange={event => setSearchString(event.target.value)}
          />
          <Grid container spacing={4} style={{ padding: 24 }}>
            {courses.map((course, index) => (
              <Grid key={index} item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                <Course course={course} />
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </div>
      ) : "No courses found"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit FORM VALUES]

Comment: Happy to have helped